# Objective-c + OpenGL ES 2.0 error drawing iOS 6+

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I programmed an application that draws objects using opengl es 2.0. The application is tested on the iPhone with iOS 5.1.1 and 6+. iOS 5.1.1 no problem with rendering. But iOS 6+ when rendering shows an object that does not have to be physically drawn. It is a square, which changes according to zooming or panning scenes. I attach screenshot and video. I am a beginner in OpenGL and objective-C and it will be my stupid mistake.

Image:
[Image with error.](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/cti1.png/)

Video:
[Video with error](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svaM2gwQWbY)

Thank you for your advice.

viewDidLoad:

```
    ....
    GLKView *glkView = (GLKView *)self.view;
    glkView.delegate = self;
    glkView.context = self.context;
    glkView.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
    glkView.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
    self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    effect2 = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    textures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ....
```

draw method:

```
    - (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        glClearColor([[set.paperColor objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]/255.0, [[set.paperColor   objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]/255.0, [[set.paperColor objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]/255.0,  [[set.paperColor objectAtIndex:3] floatValue]);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // draw point
        if ([[root objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[PointO class]])
        {
            [effect prepareToDraw];
            [self drawPoint:[root objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        // example draw texture
        if ([[root objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[Text class]])
        {
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            for (int j = 0; j < indexes.count; j++)
            {
                int index = [[indexes objectAtIndex:j]intValue];
                if (index == (i+1)) {
                    Sprite *sprite = [textures objectAtIndex:j];
                    [sprite render:[root objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }
            glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        }
```

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like the cause of your problem here. Since you're making several draw calls, though, the [Xcode Frame Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/debugging_opengl_es_frame.html) should be able to help you narrow down to the one that's drawing the extra junk.

Comment: Thank you, i try Xcode Frame Debugger.